# Laravel getting error on ajax call. unexpected return

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here.

Making a call to a laravel route like so:

```
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'api/search-scan',
  headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $( "#token-auth" ).val(),
    },
  data: { 'someOtherData': 'hi there' },
  success: function(data, status, xhr){
   console.log(status);
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, message){
    console.log(status);
  },

  });
```

Route in api with route middleware:

```
Route::post('search-scan', 'JobController@scanSearchOrder');
```

JobController:

```
 public function scanSearchOrder(Request $request)
 {

   return response('Update Successfully.', 200);
   // return response()->json('hit');

 }
```

Error:

```
message: "syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)"
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JobController response should be as follows:

```
public function scanSearchOrder(Request $request)
 {

   return response()->json(['message' => 'Update Successfully.'], 200);
   
 }
```

Latest Laravel response documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses)

Comment: Getting the same error with the above answer.

Comment: your api url is 'api/search-scan' and your route is 'search-scan' - do you have route prefix?

Comment: yes it's in api route middleware auth:api

Comment: please have look on your controller may be missing ( or { somewhere!

Comment: That's what I suspected and indeed that was it.  I'll mark this as the correct answer anyways.